# R integration with asp.net and ssas

Tags: asp.net, r, azure, ssas

Maybe someone knows if it's possible to send data from ms sql database to R server, so it could calculate some columns and send them back to ms sql again?
I am not that much familiar with R server's integration and I am cautious that is not even possible. If this is not possible, maybe it would be possible to send them from asp.net mvc 5 using integration from .net library, but I do not think that is a good solution because the data can have more then 500k rows so it would be extremely slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying a database from a server running R requires three things:

- Network security that allows you to communicate between the machines
- Drivers installed on the R server
- Configurations that allow you to connect to the database from R

In general, it is best to have your IT/Ops team take care of the Networking security and the installation of drivers, since these are things that they likely have security procedures around. We recommend using the RStudio Professional Drivers, which are easy to install and designed to work with our products.

Then, when it comes to the connection from R to the database, we recommend using the odbc package, which is a [DBI](http://db.rstudio.com/dbi/) compliant interface to using ODBC drivers.  You can acquire the latest stable version from CRAN with install.packages("odbc").

In general, a connection looks something like this:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQLServer",
                 Server = "mysqlhost",
                 Database = "mydbname",
                 UID = "myuser",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
                 Port = 1433)
```

The rstudioapi::askForPassword function will prompt the user for a password and reduce the need to store passwords in code. For more options on securing credentials, there is a [dedicated article](http://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/managing-credentials/) on the topic.  Note that there is also support for DSNs:

```
# Using a DSN
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "mydbalias")
```

for other reference please visit this [url](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/reporting-services/making-data-analytics-simpler-sql-server-and-r/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please accept as an answer if it helped.